# Reduce number of files in doxygen documentation

Tags: documentation, doxygen

Is there any way to reduce number of files generated by doxygen(may be by combining some of them)
For my project(c++ project with class hierarchy graphs enabled), the documentation consists of over 86,000 files which is a nightmare from filesystem POV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without reducing doc content, I don't think there is a solution. What you can do:

- disable index (ALPHABETICAL_INDEX)
- disable all graphviz generated plots (class diagrams, file dependency graphs). These 
  generate a high number of images, but also a lot of map files.

On a current project of mine (small compared to yours...), "full" doxygen configuration generated 873 files (19.8 MB), while the "reduced" config. generated 278 files (3.4 MB). This gives you an idea.

Oh, and another idea: generate pdf (through Latex) instead of html. You'll reduce down to 1 file ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid file system problems I suggest to set `CREATE_SUBDIRS` to `YES` in the config file. This will make doxygen distribute the output files evenly over 4096 sub-directories.

Comment: thanks. and I have already done it.
But still, can I somehow reduce total NUMBER of files?